# XSLT, how to only process first X items?

Tags: xslt, rss

I am trying to use XSL to convert a news feed into a fragment of html for insertion into a web page.

The news feed is several hundred items long and so I only want to include the latest 10 headlines... The xsl is below, I was thinking I could have a counter and break out of the loop after the desired number of iterations. However after a bit of reading it seems xsl is not designed to be used this way.

What is the "best" way to get the desired result in xsl?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

edit: Doesn't seem to let me post xml snippets. But the pattern I am following was lifted from here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0407.html

Comment: To include xml snippets in your text, you must ensure they are formatted as code. The easiest way to do this is select the text in question, then click the 'code' button in the editing toolbar (the one that says 101010).

Comment: what do you mean by "latest"? Document order? By some date value inside element or attribute?

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:for-each select="howto/topic[position() &lt;= 10]">
```

Comment: Also in pattern like `match="howto/topic[11 > position()]"`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to solve it using XPath query and no using XSLT. XPath has a two functions, one is [count( nodeset )](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp) and another is [position()](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp). With combination of these functions you can get interesting results. For example:

```
//news[position()<11]
```

returns first 10 items

or

```
//news[position()>count(//news)-10]
```

returns last 10 items